# Meaning of $\frac{dx}{f(x,y)}=\frac{dy}{g(x,y)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

> Consider the rotation group $SO(2)$ which has infinitesimal generator
> $v = -y\partial_x +x\partial _y$. The corresponding characteristic
> system is $$\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}.$$ This first order ordinary
> differential equation is easily solved; the solutions are $x^2+y^2=c$
> for $c$ an arbitrary constant.

I don't really understand the form of the ODE. Does it really mean $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$? and that the solutions are $y = \pm\sqrt{c-x^2}$ for any $c$? Why write it into this weird form?

Comment: Presumably because they've previously discussed the fact that the infinitesimal generator $A\partial_x + B\partial_y$ leads to the characteristic system $dx/A = dy/B$. Go back and figure out what this means.

Answer (score 2):

This is an exact equation, an equation for the direction field. It allows for instance for vertical directions where in the explicit DE that you derived you get division by zero. Also, in this exact form the whole circles are solutions while in the explicit DE only the upper and lower half arcs are solution.

So yes, there is a reason to write the Lagrange equations that way, it leaves open some flexibility of how they get translated into an ODE system, and in some cases allows wider manipulations to characterize the solutions completely with first integrals.

Comment: Interesting, I never heard about [exact equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation#Example). So in my case the exact equation would be $xdx+ydy=0$? In wiki, they note that a potential for this function is $F(x,y) = x^2+y^2+c$ but why is the solution $F(x,y)=0$ i.e. $x^2+y^2=-c$? In other words why do we equate the potential to zero for the solution? Also the potential would be different if we have the form $\frac{dx}{y}+\frac{dy}{x}=0$ no? In the end I am also confused why it is called an ODE since we have to solve for partial derivatives to get the potential.

Comment: Because by construction, the direction field is tangent to the level curves of the first integral (which is a function like $F$). Nomenclature is not very fixed here, most often exact DE are grouped as part of ODE. The method of characteristics also only works properly as manual exercise in select cases, it is also part of the design of numerical methods like FVM, finite-volume methods.

Comment: User
thank you. I feel a bit slow to understand, but in the end what concretely does it mean for $x^2+y^2=c$ to be a solution of $\frac{dx}{y}+\frac{dy}{x}$. I mean, what is the concrete computation we do on $x^2+y^2=c$ to check that it solves $\frac{dx}{y}+\frac{dy}{x}$?

Comment: With exact DE the solution is a curve, a geometric object. With ODE, the solution is a dynamical process. The difference is minimal, but it is there. When comparing them, a solution curve for an exact DE can be larger than the graph of a corresponding ODE solution. With the integration you got $x^2+y^2$ as a first integral. The solution curves lie on the level surfaces. As the level surfaces are already 1-dimensional, they already are the solution curves. If you add the equations for $z$, then you only get a 2D surface in $(x,y,z)$ space, and you need a further restriction to get curves.